# navigation.getParam with react navigation reference

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, state

I have a post component with a profileImage component that contains a prop called userHandle. From the post component, the userHandle is passed down all the way to profileImage. When I click on a profile image in the post component, I have a reference to a navigation stack because these post component are everywhere. Here is the rootNavigation file:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { StackActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

export const navigationRef: any = React.createRef();

export function navigate(name: any, params: any) {
  navigationRef.current?.navigate(name, params);
}

export function getParam(name: any, defaultData: any) {
  navigationRef.current?.getParam(name, defaultData);
}

export function push(name: any, params: any) {
  navigationRef.current?.dispatch(StackActions.push(name, params));
}
```

Then here is the navigation stack file with all the screens connected:

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { navigationRef } from './RootNavigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { Image } from 'react-native';
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';
import HomeTabs from './HomeTabs';
import CommentsScreen from '../PushScreens/CommentsScreen';
import SingleProfileScreen from '../PushScreens/SingleProfileScreen';

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator();

class HomeStackScreen extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
        <HomeStack.Navigator
          initialRouteName='Home'
          mode='modal'
          screenOptions={{
            headerStyle: {
              shadowColor: 'transparent'
            },
          }}
        >
          <HomeStack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeTabs} options={{headerShown:false}}/>
          <HomeStack.Screen name="CommentsScreen" component={CommentsScreen} 
            options={{
              
              headerTitle:'Discussions',
              headerBackImage: () => (
                <Icon 
                  style={{marginLeft: 20}}
                  name='arrow-down' 
                  type='material-community' 
                  color='#000000' 
                  size={30}
                />
              ),
              headerBackTitleVisible: false
            }}
          />
          <HomeStack.Screen name="SingleProfileScreen" component={SingleProfileScreen}
            options={{
              headerTitle:'',
              headerBackImage: () => (
                <Icon 
                  style={{marginLeft: 20}}
                  name='arrow-down' 
                  type='material-community' 
                  color='#000000'
                  size={30}
                />
              ),
              headerBackTitleVisible: false
            }}
          />
      </HomeStack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
    )
  }
}

export default HomeStackScreen;
```

Now from anywhere, I can import RootNavigation as RootNavigation and call:

```
RootNavigation.push('SingleProfileScreen', {userHandle: props.userHandle})}
```

And it would push that screen on top of any stack. So all is good so far. The only problem is that when I try to get the data userHandle that the screen is pushed with, I'm unable to figure out how to get that data on the SingleProfileScreen. I've tried: getParam('userHandle') multiple ways and I keep getting that is not a function. I've tried with this.props.navigation.getParam, tried with RootNavigation.getParam, and others but no luck. I just need to pass the userHandle because I need to load the data on SingleProfileScreen associated with that userHandle with componentDidMount. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

## Try using a react context API

you can pass in your value into a context API and access it in all the child screen with

```
this.context.userHandle
```

- Create a file and use this code

```
import React,{Context} from 'react'

const userHandle=React.createContext()

export const userHandleProvider=userHandle.Provider
export const userHandleConsumer=userHandle.Consumer
```

- Import it to into your component

```
import {userHandleProvider} from 'YOUR PATH'
```

wrap your navigation container in user HandleProvider

```
<UserHandleProvider value={"WHATEVER VALUE YOU WANT TO PASS"}
<NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
        <HomeStack.Navigator
          initialRouteName='Home'
          mode='modal'
          screenOptions={{
            headerStyle: {
              shadowColor: 'transparent'
            },
          }}
        >
          <HomeStack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeTabs} options={{headerShown:false}}/>
          <HomeStack.Screen name="CommentsScreen" component={CommentsScreen} 
            options={{
              
              headerTitle:'Discussions',
              headerBackImage: () => (
                <Icon 
                  style={{marginLeft: 20}}
                  name='arrow-down' 
                  type='material-community' 
                  color='#000000' 
                  size={30}
                />
              ),
              headerBackTitleVisible: false
            }}
          />
          <HomeStack.Screen name="SingleProfileScreen" component={SingleProfileScreen}
            options={{
              headerTitle:'',
              headerBackImage: () => (
                <Icon 
                  style={{marginLeft: 20}}
                  name='arrow-down' 
                  type='material-community' 
                  color='#000000'
                  size={30}
                />
              ),
              headerBackTitleVisible: false
            }}
          />
      </HomeStack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>

</UserHandleProvider>
```

you can read more into react context API
[React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Comment: Wouldn't this just work for a static context value. The user handle is different for every post, so when a user clicks on a profile picture, I would have to pass that new user handle and push that profile screen with the user handle. I get what your saying though, seemed like it would work, but I tried to implement it and couldn't figure out how it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, all I had to do is call

```
const { userHandle } = this.props.route.params;
```

in the componentDidMount() function in the singleProfileScreen and it worked